# How do I use a compiled binary for a C library on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded the libftp source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libftp/code/9/tree/), and compiled it using make. Now I just have a binary called "ftp" in the same directory. Do I need to move it to one of the root directories, like /usr/bin? Do I still need the source files so that I can #include the library?

Comment: If you want to make it really like a library, you would need to build the object, then pack it into library format using `ar` (see http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/buildlib.html for example). The resulting file would then go into your C lib path somewhere and you could reference it on the compilation line via `gcc -lmylib myprogram.c` for example.

Comment: To be honest, I have always struggled with fully grasping the full concept of libraries and how they work from the ground up. I don't really know HOW I want to do it, I just want to use it the way it was intended. So what might be the next step if I currently have a compiled binary? How do I get to the point where I can type `#include <...>` and start using it?

Comment: The `#include` just tells your program how it's defined. The linker will then need to find it somehow. One way is to just have the object (`.o`) file in a known directory and say, `gcc myprog.c /path_to/mylib.o`. That's the simplest way. If you want to use it in a bunch of different programs elsewhere, then making it a lib makes sense. The link I provided explains the process of making a lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a library in your own code, first you need that library - generally named lib{name}.a or lib{name}.so. The library will be required during linking. So when you make, make sure it creates the library and not just the ftp binary.

Secondly, at compile time you will need the header files so that the `#include`'s don't throw errors. So as far as source goes, you will at least need the header files.

Comment: OK. So I'll take all the `*.o` files and use `ar` to make a `libftp.a` file. Move that file to /usr/lib. Then move all the `.h` files to /usr/include. Then I should be able to `#include` the main header in my own code and link the library during compile time?

Comment: Yes, except you might think about putting the library in /usr/local/lib and the header files in /usr/local/include.

Comment: Thats right. One more thing to note is that gcc (or whichever compiler you are using) should be able to find the lib and .h files. So make sure all your flags (I, L, l, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc) are set properly.